# How to filter gender

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi I need some help on how to filter gender.

I already have some codes and it works fine. When I type female all female students appear but when I tried to type male both gender(male and female) appears. Is their another way on how how to filter gender?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SearchStudent()
    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM StudentInformation WHERE (" + cbxSearch.SelectedItem + " )LIKE('%" + TxtBoxFind.Text + "%'); ")
    If NoErrors(True) = False Then Exit Sub
    dgvData.DataSource = Access.DBDT
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove your wildcard from your query

> "SELECT * FROM StudentInformation WHERE (" + cbxSearch.SelectedItem +
>   " )LIKE('%" + TxtBoxFind.Text + "%'); "

The '%' characters are wildcard, so it will match anything with 'male' in it, like 'female'.  Try removing them, or just use an = operator.

Answer (score 2):

When text is 'female' the criteria is `like '%female%'`. When text is 'male' criteria is `like '%male%'`

And **female** IS `like '%male%' (fe-male).

A simplest solution is remove wildcard

```
Access.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM StudentInformation WHERE (" + cbxSearch.SelectedItem + " )LIKE('" + TxtBoxFind.Text + "'); ")
```